# Let uiscrollview dynamically adjust to uitextview height

Tags: ios, swift

My structure consist of

```
- uiview
  - scrollview
    - contentview
      - uitextview
      - uibutton
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to adjust the height of scrollview according to textview height or content. Textview gets its text on run accordingly. So when i have a long text in my textview, scrollview adjusts itself so all textview's content is visible by scrolling.

Comment: `UITextView` is used to display content that should display in several pages.If you want to display all content please use `UILabel`.

Comment: `UITextView` Supports things that `UILabel` doesn't but that latipov15 may need, like editing, selecting, and data detectors.

Comment: `UITextView` already inherits from `UIScrollView` and will automatically be scrollable when its content does not fit in its frame. Is there any reason why you have it nested within a Scroll View? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/

Comment: Yes i know by default UITextView is scroll-able. But in my case, UITextView is not scroll-able but instead I want the UIScrollView extend it's content (it's height) when UITextView text is too long.